# Стрнное позиционирование кнопки

Tags: html

Подскажите в чём можеть быть проблема, не могу расположить кнопку и поле поиска на одной линии.

```css
.input {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #b1b1b1;
  box-shadow: inset 0 5px 9px rgba(194, 195, 195, 0.4);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.search__input {
  display: inline-block;
}

.input_search {
  padding: 6px 6px;
  width: 216px;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.button {
  width: 28px;
  background: url('../img/search-button.png');
  height: 31px;
  /* added to see the button */
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: gray; 
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <div class="search__input">
    <input class="input input_search" placeholder="Enter your keyword here...">
  </div>
  <div class="search__input">
    <div class="button"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: изображение кнопки]

Answer (score 0):

```
.search__input {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. А в чём была проблема, можете подсказать?